# Matlab nested parfor loops inside functions, will all workers be used if the outer loop is small?

Tags: multithreading, matlab, parfor

If I understand the documentation correctly I can have a parfor loop inside another parfor loop as long as the inner loop is in a separate function call, which is true in my case.

My question is simply this:

In some instances my outer loop only uses 2 threads/workers. I have 6 workers in my parallel pool.

Will the inner parfor loop take advantage of the 4 unused workers?

Comment: You should be able to use `pool = gcp; pool.NumWorkers` from within the inner for loop to get information on how many workers are being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MATLAB's own documentation (http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/nesting-and-flow-in-parfor-loops.html):

> The body of a parfor-loop cannot contain another parfor-loop. But it
>   can call a function that contains another parfor-loop.
>
> However, because **a worker cannot open a parallel pool, a worker cannot
>   run the inner nested parfor-loop in parallel**. This means that only one
>   level of nested parfor-loops can run in parallel. If the outer loop
>   runs in parallel on a parallel pool, the inner loop runs serially on
>   each worker. If the outer loop runs serially in the client (e.g.,
>   parfor specifying zero workers), the function that contains the inner
>   loop can run the inner loop in parallel on workers in a pool.

As a worker cannot itself open a pool, the inner parfor loop will work in a serial manner.